# How to do MSMQ routing over HTTP?

Tags: http, routes, msmq, forwarding

Ì have a setup where I have a chain of servers that I need to send messages between:

```
A -> B -> C
```

On A I have an application which puts a message on a local MSMQ queue (MSMQ-A) on A. This queue needs to forward the message to a MSMQ queue on B (MSMQ-B) which in turn should forward the message to a MSMQ queue on C (MSMQ-C). On C there is an application which listens to messages from MSMQ-C.

The messages do not need to be transactional.

How do I configure MSMQ-A and MSMQ-B for forwarding of messages?

**UPDATE**

Based on the suggested answer I have done this:

I've enabled HTTP support under the Windows Message Queuing feature. 
I've added a mapping file under the System32/msmq/mappings folder looking like this:

```
<redirections xmlns="msmq-queue-redirections.xml">
   <redirection> 
     <from>http://machineA/msmsq/private$/logger</from>
     <to>http://machineB/msmq/private$/logger</to>
   </redirection>
</redirections>
```

and still the messages get stuck on machineA.

I am using powershell to send the messages to the queue on A like this:  Get-MsmqQueue -name logger | Send-MsmqQueue -body "asdasd"

Answer (score 0):

The design you are describing is not something that MSMQ provides.

MSMQ delivers a message from sender to receiver and that's it. You can't have a chain where the receiver automatically becomes the sender to the next receiver. You would need to write an application on each machine that receives the message from the queue and creates a NEW copy of it to send to the next.

MSMQ routing is a different concept. Compare it to parcel shipping where a parcel is routed through different depots across the country until it reaches the final destination. Each depot does nothing with the parcel except to pass it on. They don't open up the parcel, use the contents, and then repackage to send to the next depot.

You may instead be wanted to redirect MSMQ messages. For example, if A is an Internet-based PC, B is an Internet-facing server and C is a PC on an internal LAN (and you want to send A->B->C). If you have that sort of scenario then you need to look at Redirections.

[Delivering Messages Sent over the Internet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms701477(v=vs.85).aspx)

[HTTP Message Redirection](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731558(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: So how would I setup a system so that if B and C are down messages will not be lost. Is it enough to setup an MSMQ server on A?

Also I do not quite understand the articles.. where should I do the routing. On an instance of MSMQ? On which server would I setup the mappings?

Comment: All machines that are involved with MSMQ messages are MSMQ servers that use store-and-forward to prevent messages being lost. So A+B+C would all need MSMQ installed with the HTTP support option.

"where should I do the routing?"
You are redirecting, not routing. It may sound pedantic but they are different concepts in MSMQ. 
A sends messages over HTTP to a queue on the Internet-facing side of B. B has a redirection file that maps that queue to the real destination queue on C. The queue on B doesn't actually need to exist. It's just a way of hiding the internal queue name used by C.